# Trigger animation of an object when clicking on it

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint, animation, slideshow, shapes

In my PowerPoint slide, I have 3 cubes and I only want to run the animation of a cube when clicking on it. The animations of the other cubes should not run if I didn't click on them. For example, if I click on cube 2, it will run its chain of animations ignoring that cube 1 didn't run.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you're asking if you can have an animation run if it gets clicked on regards of all the other cubes that did not run their animation?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the "Animations" tab and activate the "Animation Pane"

[image]

2. Right-click on your object/shape and select "Effect Options"

[image]

3. Switch to the "Timing" tab and open the "Triggers"

[image]

4. Select "Start effect on click" and select the same object that you are currently editing. In this example, I'm editing the effects for "Rectangle 3", so I also select "Rectangle 3" for that dropdown.

[image]

5. Click on "OK" and have a great presentation :)